# ¿Cómo crear un archivo webhook en PHP?

Tags: json, api, webhook

les comento.

Proceso pagos a través de un portal llamado "Conekta" en México. El mismo me permite recibir pagos recurrentes a través de una transferencia de fondos.

Una vez hecha esta transferencia envia un webhook, si el mismo no es recibido es rebotado al cliente.

El problema surge aquí, no se como crear un archivo que reciba el webhook ya que soy algo nuevo en esto de PHP.

Según la documentación este es el código de ejemplo:

```
<?php

$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($body);
http_response_code(200); // Return 200 OK 

if ($data->type == 'charge.paid'){
  $msg = "Tu pago ha sido comprobado.";
 mail("fulanito@conekta.com","Pago confirmado",$msg);

}
```

Sin embargo lo copie y pegue tal cual solo cambiando el type por "order.created" sin embargo no funciona.

Me sigue rebotando los pagos.

La URL de la documentación es esta: https://developers.conekta.com/page/webhooks

Yo no necesito almacenar nada, ni realmente hacer mucho con los datos que reciba, ya que manejaremos todo desde el panel del proveedor "Conekta" pero este webhook es obligatorio y solo necesito que le responda el webhook que es correcto para que deje pasar la transferencia.

https://developers.conekta.com/page/pagos-v%C3%ADa-spei-recurrente

Agradecería cualquier ayuda que me pudiesen facilitar.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier De hecho puedo ver que el sistema del proveedor hace un "ping" y este es correcto, devuelve un 200. Sin embargo cuando intento hacer el pago me lo rebota, de acuerdo a un articulo esto pasa porque no puede "entregar el webook" .

Lo único que me dijeron fue "Confirma que tu webhook este recibiendo como mínimo el evento ORDER.CREATED" pero no se como hacerlo y su documentación es escasa para quienes no entendemos mucho de esto.

Comment: Si lo realice y tampoco funcionó, de hecho lo puse en la propia pregunta, ya me contacte con el proveedor y tampoco saben que relajo traen